# Why Windows is not showing in the Dual-Boot menu and boot into Ubuntu directly?

Tags: software, software-recommendations, software-assistance, windows-operating-system

It's been more than a month that I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a desktop along side with windows (Probably 10 or 11) that was already on the desktop. Now I noticed that the computer boot directly into Ubuntu I checked again and Windows is not appearing in the boot menu. I don't know what happened or how to fix that. I tried some commands that I found in the internet like `sudo f-disk -l`  and it displayed that:

```
.
.
.
Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     264191     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2      264192 1795461119 1795196928   856G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  3590658048 3591708671    1050624   513M EFI System
/dev/sda4  3591708672 3907028991  315320320 150.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  1795461120 3590658047 1795196928   856G Linux filesystem
.
.
.
```

`sudo os-prober` is not showing anything

How can I fix this issue please?

Comment: I recommend you to install GRUB Customizer. There, you will see the grub (boot) menu. Some updates add new entries to the grub menu always at the top, moving down your previous entries. Maybe your Windows entry was moved way down.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has no relation to matter modeling. The question should be moved to the UNIX stack exchange.

Comment: @Camps I did that but nothing linked to Windows is displayed in 'List configuration'

Answer (score 2):

You can try this tool to regenerate GRUB :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

And fix the dual boot. For Windows only :

[MBR Repair](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51782.fixing-corrupted-mbr-in-windows-10.aspx)!